# django: sort the table data according alphabetically

Tags: python, django, sorting

What I have is:

models.py:

```
class Address(custom_mixins.SiteAwareAbstractModel):
states = State.objects.all()

CHOICES = list()

for state in states:
    CHOICES.append((state.code, state.name))

CHOICES = tuple(CHOICES)
state_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=CHOICES)
```

Then the State class

```
class State(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
code = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

This renders all the states as they're stored in the table. What I want is to display all the states in the alphabetically order. I tried doing:

```
states = State.objects.all().order_by(
    'name').values_list(
    'code', flat=True)
```

But this threw the error

> CHOICES.append((state.code, state.name))
>        AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'code'

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
states = State.objects.all().values_list('code', 'name', named=True).order_by('name')

for state in states:
    CHOICES.append((state.code, state.name))
```

**[More information on the `values_list` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)**